# estimate missing edge weight (travel duration) in a complete graph

Tags: navigation, geospatial, graph-theory, completion

I have a complete (fully connected) graph where each node is a geographic location. The edge weights describe the time it takes to walk from one location to the other (along some road network). Now I add a new node (location) into the graph. Because querying the walking duration from the new node to all the other nodes is expensive, I only want to query a subset.

**How can I estimate the walking duration from the new node to the remaining locations?**

Given that I have the walking duration between *all* existing nodes and between the new node and a subset of the existing nodes it should be possible to come up with a good estimation for the remaining connections.

Comment: This looks like a good application for a quadtree https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

Answer (score 1):

```
Store all locations in a data structure that makes finding neighbors efficient  
      ( quadtree https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree )

Find neighbors of new location.

Query walking distance from new location and neighbours

Loop over all other locations

   Find neighbour closest to other location

   Estimate distance from new location to other by sum of
          distance from new to neighbor and neighbou to other.
```

I have implemented a quadtree search for neighbours of a point and compared the performance with a simple search through a vector of points.   If there are less than 100 points to search, the performances are similar, at less than a microsecond for each search. For more than 100 points, the advantage of a quadtree becomes significant.

[image]

[Here is the code.](https://github.com/JamesBremner/quadtree)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think this poses an upper bound on the estimation because the walking distance between two locations can't be longer than walking there passing another location. However I stumbled upon Inverse Distance Weighted interpolation. I tried IDW and it empirically works better. There is also Kriging which seems like an overkill for my case.